# Disqus comment box not showing (at all)

Tags: javascript, django, disqus

When following the tutorial found on Disqus the comment-box won't render. It seems to be setup correct from the admin found on disqus.

```
var disqus_config = function () {
   this.page.url = {{request.build_absolute_uri}}; // {{request.build_absolute_uri}} is what is says | Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
   this.page.identifier = {{instance.id}}; // {{instance.id}} article unique ID | Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
```

The `{{request.build_absolute_uri}}` returns `http://localhost:8000/posts/*[post_title]*/`
And the page identifier `instance.id` is an integer incrementing by one for each post (eg *2*)

I have also set the domain on discuss to be `http://localhost:8000/posts/` (since as of now it raises a 404 error when not specifying a sub-url)

```
(function() { 
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

s.src = '//trydjango19.disqus.com/embed.js';

s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
```

I have also linked the comment count JS file, as well as appending #disqus_thread to all links on the homepage

Comment: What's your question? Do you get any error messages? Any files that fail to load?

Comment: What does this sentence mean? _"I have also set the domain on discuss to be http://localhost:8000/posts/ "_ What have you set, and where? `http://localhost:8000/posts/` is not a domain. It's a url.

Comment: @HåkenLid Sorry, I confused urls and domains. Actually it doesn't do anything since it has no way of connecting to localhost, but you seem to have found the right answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you get valid javascript from this?

```
this.page.url = {{request.build_absolute_uri}};
```

I would expect that `this.page.url` should be a string. In which case you probably have to wrap it in quotes. `instance.id` should probably be a string well, since that's how it's done in [the examples in the disqus docs](https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables#thispageidentifier).

```
this.page.url = "{{request.build_absolute_uri}}";
this.page.identifier = "{{instance.id}}";
```

Comment: Your original code would cause a javascript exception. You don't mention any error messages, but they can be found in your web browser's javascript console. You can also inspect the rendered javascript code using the browser's development tools.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew that. The server didn't send any error messages, so I assumed the code was (logically) working.